# Is there any function like to_date (oracle) for Impala?

Tags: oracle, bigdata, impala

I would like to manipulate **date** through `Impala-shell` with a function similar to
`TO_DATE( string1 [, format_mask] [, nls_language] )` from **Oracle**. Is there any suggestions on how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impala supports many date conversion functions.  The closest one to Oracle's `TO_DATE()` is  `FROM_TIMESTAMP()`.

For more details see [Impala Date and Time Functions](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html).